# SVG background not displaying in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

Works fine in Firefox and Chrome. Safari just doesn't display my SVG background image. What's the deal?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <header class="span12 hero-unit">
            <h1>Timeline</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="svg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.svg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(../img/mars.svg);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Link

http://distantfuturejosh.com/timeline/

Comment: You are aware that http://distantfuturejosh.com/timeline/img/mars.svg is just a base64-encoded png image inside an svg wrapper? So, you could just use a png instead. Though it would likely be quite small as a true vector graphic. My guess is that data URIs in svg backgrounds is disallowed (or buggy) in Safari.

Comment: Erik, I had a suspicion I was not saving the file correctly in Illustrator! This explains why it only scales to a certain point without losing quality. I guess I need to post on an Adobe form to find out how to live trace a raster image and convert it to a purely vector svg.

Comment: Erik, do you get rep when your comment is up voted? I don't want to accept my answer as correct when it was you that made me realize what I was doing wrong. But I don't want this question to go unanswered either...

Comment: Please accept the answer that solves the problem, it helps other people too. Don't worry about the rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my problem was a graphics software issue, not a web code problem. But for the record, what I was doing was opening a raster psd in Illustrator and saving it as an svg. That just embedded a png inside an svg as Erik pointed out. To fix this, I simply selected the object in illustrator, chose Object > Image Trace > Make. Then I selected my preferred image tracing preset (6 colors) and saved that as an svg. Works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it leaving off the "-image" like this?

```
background: url(../img/mars.svg);
```

Reference [Using SVG as a background-image](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

Comment: Tried removing `-image` per your suggestion. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: @wetjosh Do you have any other versions of safari / machines running Safari to confirm it's not just that one machine?

Comment: Ok, just tested it on an older Mac running Safari 5 (one version older than the current) but still does not work. Thanks for the ideas though.

Answer (score -1):

I was just searching out about SVG background that was not working on Windows safari and after extensive search I found this issue. I was using it with linear gradient 
like this

```
background:url("../images/cover-blue-nodots.svg"), linear-gradient(87deg, #0577f4 0px, #53d3d4 100%);
```

it was not working and I just use webkit and provide it all this stuff in it and it works.

```
background:url("../images/cover-blue-nodots.svg"), linear-gradient(87deg, #0577f4 0px, #53d3d4 100%);
background:url("../images/cover-blue-nodots.svg"), -webkit-linear-gradient(87deg, #0577f4 0px, #53d3d4 100%);
```