# Background image not displaying in safari 5.17

Tags: css

The site is here http://crea8tion.com/ChristmasMessage/index.html

for some reason the background is not displaying in safari 5.17 browser.

Not sure what I've overlooked? (No issue with background in any other major browser)

Relevant CSS code as follows:

```
body {
background-image: url("img/background.svg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-origin:border;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415072/svg-background-not-displaying-in-safari?

Comment: Try adding webkit vendor-prefix, `-webkit-background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be an issue with the svg. Some useful info on the link provided by @donte

I actually just switched the svg for a png to resolve.